# TFS 2015 Web Hook to Slack Integration

Tags: c#, tfs-2015, slack-api, tfs-workitem, asp.net-webhooks

I have got a requirement,

When a work item is created (and status -say  In progress) in TFS 2015(not vsts), I want my web hook to fire a post method which ll create a Channel in Slack, and invite few folks.

2) Once the Bug is closed -  read all the history of channel and push the history back to Bug.

I was able to achieve the same with TFS server side plugin and it's working, but requirement got changed to Web hooks.

Could someone help me on how to achieve custom web hook.which ll enable events from TFS WI to Slack please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can not create new incoming webhooks in slack programmatically, but you can use any existing incoming webhook for a new channel.

Just add the channel property in your message to the webhook.

Example from the Slack documentation:

```
curl -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "This is posted to #general and comes from *monkey-bot*.", "channel": "#general", "link_names": 1, "username": "monkey-bot", "icon_emoji": ":monkey_face:"}' \
https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So to implement your requirement I suggest you create a new channel and invite users as needed through the Slack web API. And then use an existing incoming webhook to send messages to that channel.

Answer (score 0):

TFS has default slack service hook which can post a message to a channel. The API looks like below:

```
POST http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=3.2
Content-Type: application/json
{
"consumerActionId":"postMessageToChannel",
"consumerId":"slack",
"consumerInputs":{
    "url":"https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx"},
    "eventType":"workitem.created",
    "publisherId":"tfs",
    "publisherInputs":{
        "areaPath":"",
        "workItemType":"",
        "projectId":"77e3c775-dc30-4354-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
}
```

For your second requirement, you need to check Slack Api to see how to read all the history of channel, and use [Update work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items) to update Bug work items.